# Compiler error on Stopped enum value using GetStatus

Tags: c++, audio, enums, sfml, status

I'm trying to get the status of a sound effect but I don't know how to actually find out what the status is. I'm quite new to C++. I tried to read up about enums and apply what I saw, but it won't work.
Here's my code

```
sf::Sound::Status BeepStatus = Beep.GetStatus();
cout << BeepStatus;
if (BeepStatus == Stopped)
{
    Beep.SetPitch(float((rand()%15)-1)/10);
    Beep.Play();
}
```

That code won't work. During compile it will say that Stopped is not defined. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the scope operator for your Stopped variable.

Likely, it's this:

```
sf::Sound::Stopped
```